# No immediate update of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a `StudentsViewModel` class that contains an `ObservableCollection<Student>` property called `StudentsList`. The StudentsList is bound to a `DataGrid` in my `StudentsView`. When I add a new student using the `AddStudentCommand`, the new student is added to the database successfully, but the `StudentsList` in the view is not updating immediately. I have to navigate away from the view and then come back to see the updated list.

I have verified that the `AddStudent` method is correctly adding the new student to the database and also adding it to the `StudentsList` collection. However, the view does not reflect the changes right away. I believe there might be an issue with how the StudentsList is being updated or bound to the view.

I have shared the relevant code snippets below:

`StudentsViewModel.cs`

```
public class StudentsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
        DriveBuddyEntities _db;

        private ObservableCollection<Student> _studentsList;

        public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentsList
        {
            get { return _studentsList; }
            set
            {
                _studentsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StudentsList));
            }
        }

        private Student _newStudent = new Student();        

        public Student NewStudent
        {
            get => _newStudent;
            set
            {
                _newStudent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewStudent));
            }
        }

        private string _newStudentSelectedCourseCategory;

        public string NewStudentSelectedCourseCategory
        {
            get => _newStudentSelectedCourseCategory;
            set
            {
                _newStudentSelectedCourseCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewStudentSelectedCourseCategory));
            }
        }
        
        public ICommand AddStudentCommand { get; set; }

        public StudentsViewModel()
        {
            _db = new DriveBuddyEntities();
            LoadStudents();

            AddStudentCommand = new RelayCommand(AddStudent);
        }

        private void LoadStudents() => StudentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_db.Students);

        private void AddStudent(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                CourseDetail courseDetail = _db.CourseDetails.FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Category.CategoryName == NewStudentSelectedCourseCategory);

                if (courseDetail != null)
                {
                    NewStudent.CourseDetails.Add(courseDetail);
                    _db.Students.Add(NewStudent);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Student has been created", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    StudentsList.Add(NewStudent);
                    NewStudent = new Student();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid course category", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. Student has not been created. Check your data.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
}
```

`StudentsView.xaml`

```
<!--#region ===== DataGrid ===== -->
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"
                  RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle}" 
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" 
                  CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle}"  
                  Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                ....
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <!--#endregion-->
```

Comment: So what the problem actually is? What you mean by "However, the view does not reflect the changes right away." If you can view rows in your DataGrid but they are empty, you could check you Student class - every property should have get and set to be able to bind it to DataGrid. Hope this helps, if not please provide more details what you are expecting.

Comment: When add a new item to the StudentsList it is not visible in the datagrid, it is visible only after restarting the application or changing view.